# How to index mongoose-timestamp in elastic search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongoosastic

We have a [mongoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) object with schema like following, with the use of  [timestamps](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps), we are populating createdAt & updatedAt fields. We are using [mongoosastic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic) to index these in elastic search.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
                 type: String
                 es_indexed: true,
                 es_index:"analyzed"
              },
        managerId: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId},
        details:{},
        email: {
                 type: String
                 es_indexed: true,
                 es_index:"analyzed"
              },
        phone: {
                 type: Number
                 es_indexed: true,
                 es_index:"analyzed"
              }
    },
    {
        timestamps: true
    });
```

I want to index `updatedAt` as well in elastic search, but not sure how to do it with mongoosastic. Please let me know are these specific option to get this done.

Comment: How are you indexing document? What are you using to index?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mapping the date as per the [docs](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic#mapping)?
So, something like

```
var ExampleSchema = new Schema({
      // Date (core type)
      createdAt: {type:Date, es_type:'date', es_indexed: true},
      updatedAt: {type:Date, es_type:'date', es_indexed: true}
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)
```